# How to pass variables / aliases between Cypress step definitions?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to re-use a variable or alias across multiple step definitions in my Cypress / Cucumber test.

Variable declaration & 1st step def:

```
let assetName = '';

And('I click on the button', (view) => {   
  if (view === 'Grid') {
    homePage.getAssetName().first().then($el => {
    assetName = $el.text();
    }).click();
  }
});
```

2nd step def:

```
And('I verify something', (view) => {   
    cy.get('.ItgAssetDetails-name').should('have.text', + assetName);
});
```

But I get the below error message:

> expected <p.ItgAssetDetails-name> to have text NaN, but the text was lenses System

I've also tried assigning `$el.text()` an alias, but that hasn't worked either.

Can someone please show me what changes are required to pass this value between step definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely a typo since you are calling `.should('have.text', + assetName)`. The `+` is a [unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) trying to convert your string in `assetName` into a number and giving you `NaN`

```js
console.log(+"Hello there")
```

Just remove the `+`

```
.should('have.text', assetName)
```